# Why does Rust infer FnMut instead of FnOnce for this closure, even though inferring FnMut causes an error?

Tags: rust, closures, type-inference

Trying to compile this code:

```rust
fn main() {
    fn id(x: &mut u8) -> &mut u8 { x }
    let x = &mut 0_u8;
    let f = move || id(x);
}
```

results in an error:

```
error: captured variable cannot escape `FnMut` closure body
 --> main.rs:4:21
  |
4 |     let f = move || id(x);
  |                   - ^^^^^ returns a reference to a captured variable which escapes the closure body
  |                   |
  |                   inferred to be a `FnMut` closure
  |
  = note: `FnMut` closures only have access to their captured variables while they are executing...
  = note: ...therefore, they cannot allow references to captured variables to escape
```

However, if I force the closure `f` to be inferred as `FnOnce` only (not `FnMut`), as follows:

```rust
fn main() {
    fn id(x: &mut u8) -> &mut u8 { x }
    let x = &mut 0_u8;
    fn force_fn_once<F: FnOnce() -> R, R>(f: F) -> F { f }
    let f = force_fn_once(move || id(x));
}
```

then the example compiles. I have tested this on Rust 1.65.0, as well as the latest nightly release at the time, 1.68.0-nightly (2022-12-14), and both with and without declaring the closure as `move`.

Why does the Rust compiler infer `FnMut` for `f` when doing so results in an error (and when it could simply infer `FnOnce` to avoid that error)? And, as a followup question, is there a better way to force the compiler to infer `FnOnce`?

Comment: @kmdreko It is, and I think you're right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe, without inference, the compiler attempts to deduce the closure's capabilities from the least-restrictive to most-restrictive (`Fn` -> `FnMut` -> `FnOnce`). It will see that `Fn` can't work because it would need to either move or mutably reborrow `x`, but it can type-check successfully with `FnMut` because it can mutably reborrow `x` to pass to `id()`.

However, the borrow checker only runs after type-deductions and its only then that the "escaped capture" emits an error. And the compiler doesn't backtrack to try again with a different function trait.

> Is there a better way to force the compiler to infer `FnOnce`?

Something like `let f: impl FnOnce() -> _ = ...` might be available eventually, but until then, in this case you can introduce a statement to force a move of the captured variable:

```
let f = move || { let x = x; id(x) };
               // ^^^^^^^^^^
```

EDIT: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust-clippy/issues/11562#issuecomment-1750237884 suggest a more concise form:

```rust
let f = move || id({ x });
```

Comment: I'll try to see if there's a Rust issue that already reports this deficiency. Though it does sound a bit tricky to solve.